# Very strange mobile sizing issue react/react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am experiencing a very strange sizing issue where the width of all of the content on the page except for the nav bar shrinks as the device-width shrinks (on mobile).

Screenshot of Mobile: https://gyazo.com/461c5252c1f4749e6b18ed8ae7754ae0
Desktop Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/bfe36b73455cefe9803f5494f5bc1048

Here is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Equilibria Network</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the main layout of the page

```
class Main extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <div id={"main"}>
                <MainNav/>
                <MainParallax/>
                <ThreeCols/>
                <TwitterParallax/>
                <EquilibriaSection/>
                <Roadmap/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Github: https://github.com/thomasdparker1/equilibria-website-react

If you have any suggestions I would really appreciate the help! Thank you.

Comment: Hi can you put together a jsfiddle oder codepen for this (or at least show us the css), as the given code is not really enough to give a proper advise in my opinion.

Comment: Hi @davbuc, here is the code on Github: https://github.com/thomasdparker1/equilibria-website-react

Thanks for the response :)